# How to make the JMX encrypted password authentication work?

Tags: java, authentication, rmi, jmx

I'm monitoring my server with JMX remotely. However, the jmx-access and jmx-password store clear passwords which I do not want.

Followed with [How to encrypt passwords for JConsole's password file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676513/how-to-encrypt-passwords-for-jconsoles-password-file), [How to make the JMX custom authentication work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143653/how-to-make-the-jmx-custom-authentication-work) and [How do I create a Login Module?](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-create-a-login-module.html), I wrote a custom login module.

My Login Module:

```
public class EncryptedFileLoginModule implements LoginModule {
        private Subject subject;
        private CallbackHandler callbackHandler;
        private Map sharedState;
        private Map options;

        private String name;
        private String password;

        private boolean succeeded = false;

        public EncryptedFileLoginModule() {
            System.out.println("Login Module - constructor called");
        }

        public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler, Map<String, ?> sharedState,
                Map<String, ?> options) {

            System.out.println("Login Module - initialize called");
            this.subject = subject;
            this.callbackHandler = callbackHandler;
            this.sharedState = sharedState;
            this.options = options;

            System.out.println("testOption value: " + (String) options.get("testOption"));

            succeeded = false;
        }

        public boolean login() throws LoginException {
            System.out.println("Login Module - login called");
            if (callbackHandler == null) {
                throw new LoginException("Oops, callbackHandler is null");
            }

            Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[2];
            callbacks[0] = new NameCallback("name:");
            callbacks[1] = new PasswordCallback("password:", false);

            try {
                callbackHandler.handle(callbacks);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new LoginException("Oops, IOException calling handle on callbackHandler");
            } catch (UnsupportedCallbackException e) {
                throw new LoginException("Oops, UnsupportedCallbackException calling handle on callbackHandler");
            }

            NameCallback nameCallback = (NameCallback) callbacks[0];
            PasswordCallback passwordCallback = (PasswordCallback) callbacks[1];

            name = nameCallback.getName();
            password = new String(passwordCallback.getPassword());

            if ("a".equals(name) && "a".equals(password)) {
                System.out.println("Success! You get to log in!");
                succeeded = true;
                return succeeded;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failure! You don't get to log in");
                succeeded = false;
                throw new FailedLoginException("Sorry! No login for you.");
            }
        }

        public boolean abort() throws LoginException {
            System.out.println("Login Module - abort called");
            return false;
        }

        public boolean commit() throws LoginException {
            System.out.println("Login Module - commit called");
            return succeeded;
        }

        public boolean logout() throws LoginException {
            System.out.println("Login Module - logout called");
            return false;
        }

    }

    class UserPrincipal implements Principal, Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4604480892359393296L;
        private String name;

        public UserPrincipal(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return o instanceof UserPrincipal &&
                   ((UserPrincipal)o).name.equals(name);
        }
        public int hashCode() {
            return name.hashCode();
        }
    }

    class StatePrincipal implements Principal, Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8429580270033209093L;
        private String state;

        public StatePrincipal(String state) {
            this.state = state;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return state;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return state;
        }
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return o instanceof StatePrincipal && ((StatePrincipal)o).equals(state);
        }
        public int hashCode() {
            return state.hashCode();
        }
    }
```

And here is my Login Module config file (d:/mysecurity.cfg):

```
MyLoginModule {
    cn.com.singlee.slice.security.EncryptedFileLoginModule REQUIRED 
        testOption=here_is_an_option;
};
```

When starting my server, I use these parameters:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999  
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=d:/mysecurity.cfg
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.login.config=MyLoginModule
```

However, when I try to connect the server with JCsonle, I cannot login. The server seems to be able to invoke the custom authentication procudure successfully with these log output:

```
Login Module - constructor called
Login Module - initialize called
testOption value: here_is_an_option
Login Module - login called
Success! You get to log in!
Login Module - commit called
```

But JConsole reports errors (I started JConsole in debug mode with "jconsole -debug"):

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Access denied! No entries found in the access file [C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\management\jmxremote.access] for any of the authenticated identities []
    at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap$AccessFileCheckerAuthenticator.checkAccessFileEntries(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap$AccessFileCheckerAuthenticator.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl.doNewClient(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl.newClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:160)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Stub.newClient(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.getConnection(RMIConnector.java:2370)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:296)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.tryConnect(ProxyClient.java:366)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.connect(ProxyClient.java:314)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.VMPanel$2.run(VMPanel.java:295)
```

This error complains that no authenticated identities were found in jmxremote.access.

Since I use a custom authentication login module, why is jmxremote.access needed?

What's more, even if I add the test user "a" in jmxremote.access, the error still exists.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for this post the jconsole -debug was the break through

I believe what you are missing is that you have not configured "a" in the jmxremote.access, Using your above example, when i changed a few lines it worked for me

note the addition of the

```
user = new JMXPrincipal(name);
```

and using the uncommented lines in "jmxremote.access"

```
controlRole readwrite
```

I hope this helps other programmers in the same situation.

```
    public class EncryptedFileLoginModule implements LoginModule {
    private Subject subject;
    private CallbackHandler callbackHandler;
    private Map sharedState;
    private Map options;
    private JMXPrincipal user;

    private String name;
    private String password;

    private boolean succeeded = false;

    public EncryptedFileLoginModule() {
        System.out.println("Login Module - constructor called");
    }

    public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler, Map<String, ?> sharedState,
                           Map<String, ?> options) {

        System.out.println("Login Module - initialize called");
        this.subject = subject;
        this.callbackHandler = callbackHandler;
        this.sharedState = sharedState;
        this.options = options;

        System.out.println("testOption value: " + (String) options.get("testOption"));

        succeeded = false;
    }

    public boolean login() throws LoginException {
        System.out.println("Login Module - login called");
        if (callbackHandler == null) {
            throw new LoginException("Oops, callbackHandler is null");
        }

        Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[2];
        callbacks[0] = new NameCallback("name:");
        callbacks[1] = new PasswordCallback("password:", false);

        try {
            callbackHandler.handle(callbacks);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new LoginException("Oops, IOException calling handle on callbackHandler");
        } catch (UnsupportedCallbackException e) {
            throw new LoginException("Oops, UnsupportedCallbackException calling handle on callbackHandler");
        }

        NameCallback nameCallback = (NameCallback) callbacks[0];
        PasswordCallback passwordCallback = (PasswordCallback) callbacks[1];

        name = nameCallback.getName();
        password = new String(passwordCallback.getPassword());

        if ("controlRole".equals(name) && "a".equals(password)) {
            System.out.println("Success! You get to log in!");
            // Create a new user principal
            user = new JMXPrincipal(name);
            succeeded = true;
            return succeeded;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failure! You don't get to log in");
            succeeded = false;
            throw new FailedLoginException("Sorry! No login for you.");
        }
    }

    public boolean abort() throws LoginException {
        System.out.println("Login Module - abort called");
        return false;
    }

    public boolean commit() throws LoginException {
        System.out.println("Login Module - commit called");
        subject.getPrincipals().add(user);
        return succeeded;
    }

    public boolean logout() throws LoginException {
        System.out.println("Login Module - logout called");
        user = null;
        succeeded = false;
        return false;
    }

}

class UserPrincipal implements Principal, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4604480892359393296L;
    private String name;

    public UserPrincipal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof UserPrincipal &&
                ((UserPrincipal)o).name.equals(name);
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }
}

class StatePrincipal implements Principal, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8429580270033209093L;
    private String state;

    public StatePrincipal(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return state;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return state;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof StatePrincipal && ((StatePrincipal)o).equals(state);
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return state.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and clean answer... you saved my day ,thanks!